# HttpRedirect on every link within FBML application, why?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have set up the SDK on my FB application but for the life of me cannot work out why the redirection happens.

The app is an IFrame so, for testing I have two pages, on page one a link to page two, when I click the link the whole page is redirecting as opposed to the IFrame src redirecting.

Both pages are checking to see if the user is logged in with the following code..

```
protected string requiredAppPermissions = "user_about_me,email";
protected FacebookApp fbApp;
protected CanvasAuthorizer authorizer;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fbApp = new FacebookApp();
    authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer(fbApp);
    authorizer.Perms = requiredAppPermissions;



    if (authorizer.Authorize())
    {

    }


}
```

I have had a look in source and can see this in the FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, I just can't understand why you would want to keep redirecting the full page for every navigation link?

Answer (score 0):

The most important reason is that Facebook passes the authentication to the signed_request to the source on every request. It either does this with a POST in the body or with a GET in the querystring. The reason we do this is because cookies aren't 100% reliable. If we redirected inside the iframe we would have to store the user's session in a cookie. Some browsers, including safari, don't let iframe apps create cookies. There are ways around this, but for most people the way we have it works best. If you want to have a redirect inside the iframe without changing the top url you will have to save the session in some way and pass it to the second page. You could do this by adding it to the querystring (complicated) or storing it in the Session (not very scalable) or using cookies (not reliable).